# How can I append hash to URL Filename Apache Web Server Mod-Rewrite

Tags: regex, linux, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website that essentially runs based on one page. All other content is loaded dynamically, using HTML5 history and pushstate but the issue is that urls in search appear as www.mysite.com/home.html. I want these urls to be redirected and appear as www.mysite.com/#home.html so that my site content loads correctly. How can I do this?

I don't think it should be very hard but I can't seem to figure it out. 
Thank you!

Comment: "The title pretty much explains it all." no, it doesn't. "URL" is more or less unrelated to filenames, apache is a huge project, offering a lot of different servers, etc. Hash is **not** the `#` sign, that would usually be named *sharp* in a computing context, partly because "hash" refers to a completely different context.

Comment: @MarcusMüller In web context it's referred to as a hash, particularly when used in a URL. Additionally, a URL is made up of several components, including the domain name and a file name, if a filename is specified. But at your request I edited the title and question content.

Comment: No, it's not. Especially in web context, a hash is a [one-way function that maps a space of data objects to a set of hashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function); a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) is *not* generally made of these components, however it's common to see HTTP URLs (which are a special kind of URL) to follow that scheme -- there's no reason the things behind the leading `/` should correspond to an actual path.

Comment: @MarcusMüller document.location.hash is a property of an HTML document. I'm well aware both of what a hash function is, as well as the usage of sharp, which also happens to be a musical term. When speaking about URL's for a website it **is** a hash not sharp. Now, clearly I am referring to a web URL, hence the "my website" and "web server". Now, I see no point in arguing about this if you don't have a solution, but thank you for your comments, and your patronizing remarks on hashes and hash sets.

Comment: `RewriteRule home\.html$ /#home.html`?